# Disable gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme for single application

Tags: linux, theme, gtk3

I like having a dark theme, so have gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme enabled in my local settings.ini file. However, some applications (such as the ubuntu software manager) don't work will with a dark theme (usually because the apps hard code colors rather than using the theme).

Is there any way to use the light theme for a specific application, either with an environment variable like GTK_THEME, or some configuration file.

I have tried setting using `GTK_THEME:Adwaita`, but that didn't remove the dark theme.

**Edit**
I would also like to know how to do this in a KDE environment with a dark theme, especially for gtk and mono applications.

Comment: For anyone landing here from google: Setting this for mono applications does not work yet: https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/issues/277